# Amsmath \implies as subscript

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

Is there a way to use the \implies without A and B like `$f_\implies$` ?

Comment: `\f_\LongRightarrow`

Comment: You shouldn't use `\implies` for that purpose; `\Longrightarrow` is the symbol (but probably `\Rightarrow`) is better.

Comment: Thank you. Why shouldn't I?

Comment: @bob: `\implies` is a binary operator, having a special spacing, `\Longrightarrow` or `\Rightarrow` etc. is a symbol 'only', without special spacing. You want to use it as a symbol, not as an operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\implies` is

```
\DOTSB \;\Longrightarrow \;
```

and using it in `f_\implies` will produce errors. But even `f_{\implies}` would be wrong because of the added spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%$f_\implies$ % produces errors

$f_{\implies}$

$f_{\Longrightarrow}$

$f_{\Rightarrow}$

\end{document}
```

Take your pick; my preference is for the last one.

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you for this detailed answer! I replaced \implies with \Longrightarrow